# Why does Node use node_modules instead of .node_modules?

Tags: node.js, architecture, filesystems, package

I was always under the impression that settings and "meta information" should be stored in a dotfile (or in this case, a dot-directory). Why didn't Node use a local `.node_modules` directory?

Is there a technical reason? If not, is there anything written about this design decision from the team?

Comment: You're aware node_modules doesn't store settings, right?

Comment: Yeah. It's still a meta thing about your project though. Was just curious.

Comment: its not really meta... node_modules stores straight up dependencies. There are other applications in there your project depends on.

Comment: @HyoByun That's true. I suppose it seems meta to me because it's generated instead of something you commit to your repo. It's also something you would never `require` from Node, whereas all other directory names are fair game.

Answer (score 1):

The "." implies a hidden folder, which the node_modules aren't. Node modules need to be used throughout the application, sometimes by the user (such as importing minified javascript files for Angular) and therefore should not be hidden files.

Be sure not to include them in your git commits by creating a .gitignore file and adding `node_modules` to it!

Hope this helps.